# Simple python question about data visualization

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, visualization

I want a bar plot that shows the number of all diseases in 2000 for Albania.

[image: Image of data]

I tried this, but I could not get what I want.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df[country['Albania']], df['2000'])
plt.xlabel('Fruit', fontsize=17, fontname='Times New Roman')
plt.ylabel('Spent', fontsize=17, fontname='Times New Roman')
plt.title('Share of diseases in Albania in 2000 ', fontsize=17, fontname="Times New Roman")

plt.show()
```

Comment: You'll need to filter the dataframe to only 'Albania' '2000' rows. It looks like those are a Multi-Index. You've also tagged `seaborn` but it appears you're using `matplotlib` to plot.

Comment: It can be done with seaborn  or matplotlib . I did not get your point about multi index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first set up a dummy example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({('Country_%s' % c, y): {'disease_%d' % (i+1): np.random.randint(100)
                                           for i in range(4)}
                    for c,y in itertools.product(list('ABCD'), range(1998,2002))
                   }).T
df.index.names = ('country', 'year')
```

```
                disease_1  disease_2  disease_3  disease_4
country   year                                            
Country_A 1998         44         47         64         67
          1999         67          9         83         21
          2000         36         87         70         88
          2001         88         12         58         65
Country_B 1998         39         87         46         88
          1999         81         37         25         77
          2000         72          9         20         80
          2001         69         79         47         64
Country_C 1998         82         99         88         49
          1999         29         19         19         14
          2000         39         32         65          9
          2001         57         32         31         74
Country_D 1998         23         35         75         55
          1999         28         34          0          0
          2000         36         53          5         38
          2001         17         79          4         42
```

You can then subset one multi-indexed row per country and year

```
df.loc[('Country_B', 2000)]
```

output:

```
disease_1    72
disease_2     9
disease_3    20
disease_4    80
Name: (Country_B, 2000), dtype: int64
```

and plot (here using pandas+matplotlib):

```
ax = df.loc[('Country_B', 2000)].plot.bar()
ax.set_ylabel('number of cases')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. could you please help showing 2 years in one plot?

Comment: Try `df.query('country == "Country_B" & year in [2000, 2001]').plot.bar()` and `df.query('country == "Country_B" & year in [2000, 2001]').T.plot.bar()`